# How can I place an image outside wrapper div

Tags: css, html, wrapper

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now and I'm in need of some help. I would like to get the same affect as this website where an image floats next to the wrapper id but when resizing the page the image stays in place.

http://pack155.com/

Comment: In your example, the image isn't floated next to the wrapper at all. It's absolutely positioned within `#page` and is a sibling of `#content`, the "wrapper" you mention.

Comment: Hi!

First things first: you should try using Google Chrome browser to inspect the site you're trying to learn from.

The bear in the image isn't floating. It's absolutely positioned with css.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the code there:

`#page` is the wrapper of the image `#bear`

```
#page {
width: 1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

#bear {
position: absolute;
right: 3px;
top: 250px;
}
```

Comment: sorry about that this is my first time posting. Thanks

Comment: by the way this is not my site. Thank you Bram, I'm trying to understand what they are doing.

Comment: Do you understand it, or not?